# Error boundary doesn't catch error from apollo client

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, apollo, react-error-boundary

I'm trying to catch some errors on the top level, to show the most beautiful error page in the world.

For some reason, I see my nodes disconnected, but Error Boundary never fires.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ApolloClient, { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

const client = new ApolloClient({ uri: "/graphql" });
const query = gql`{ items { id }}`;

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = { hasError: false };

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error: any) {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <h1>Had error</h1>
    } else {
      return this.props.children;
    }
  }
}

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    client.query({ query })
      .then(res => setData(res))
      .catch(err => { console.warn("Error:", err); throw err; });
  }, []);

  return <pre>Data: {data}</pre>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ErrorBoundary>
      <App />
  </ErrorBoundary>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I run this in an empty create-react-app project.

I expect to see `<h1>Had error</h1>`; I get CRA unhandled error screen.

Comment: The error boundaries will only show on production builds. How are you testing to see your boundaries?

Comment: error boundaries definitely work everywhere. only the debug error overlay is not shown in production. I test it by running cra with `yarn start` (then I see debug window from react), and in production with `yarn build` && `npx serve build` (which shows the window with "Data: " string (so `hasError` never goes to true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)

> Error boundaries do **not** catch errors for:
>
> - Event handlers (learn more)
> - **Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame callbacks)**
> - Server side rendering
> - Errors thrown in the error boundary itself (rather than its children)

Promises are asynchronous, so rejected Promises won't be caught by error boundaries. At the moment, the [recommended but somewhat hackish approach](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14981) is to throw the error inside `setState`. In functional components, you can use the set function returned by the `useState` hook in place of `setState`:

```
const [, setState] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
  client.query({ query })
    .then(res => setData(res))
    .catch(err => {
      console.warn("Error:", err);
      setState(() => {
        throw err;
      });
    });
}, []);
```

Throwing inside `useEffect` would work too, but not inside a `then` or `catch` callback of a Promise. You also can't make the `useEffect` callback an `async` function because it can't return a Promise. So we're stuck with using `setState`.

Also note that there is really no reason to be calling `client.query` directly, particularly since this code will **not** rerender your UI if the cache changes. You should use `useQuery` and the `data` state already exposed by the hook for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That worked.

Regarding useQuery, This example is a minimal reproducing case, in a real world it's a query that loads data on event, so using useQuery regretfully does not work.

Comment: @yhaskell Gotcha. You may want to consider using `useLazyQuery` instead then. Also, while I get wanting to pipe all your errors through the same mechanism, you might consider adding an ErrorLink to do global error handling for Apollo Client and use the error boundary for everything else. Even if there's a bit of duplication, it'll still probably be cleaner overall. Just a suggestion.